# jQuery manage multiple star rating

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-hover, rating-system

On my website I have a page with serval results where people can bring out there rating.

With one rating list on the page everything works fine but with multiple I got a little problem by selecting the right list (this) to be hovered. Right now it's always the first list in the html code which is hovered (if I put my cursor on the second rating list first is hovering).

The html:

```
<ol class="rating" data-rating="4">
<li class="Arad5fQEnoZlv9E59d"><a title="Super boring" class="rate starOn" id="1">1 star</a></li>
<li class="Arad5fQEnoZlv9E59d"><a title="Boring" class="rate starOn" id="2">2 stars</a></li>
<li class="Arad5fQEnoZlv9E59d"><a title="Nice" class="rate starOn" id="3">3 stars</a></li>
<li class="Arad5fQEnoZlv9E59d"><a title="Cool" class="rate starOn" id="4">4 stars</a></li>
<li class="Arad5fQEnoZlv9E59d"><a title="Super cool!" class="rate star" id="5">5 stars</a></li>
<div class="response">Score 4 By 2  ratings</div>
</ol>
```

The part of my javascript who won't do the good job:

```
$('ol.rating li', this).hover(function(){
            var id      = $('a', this).attr('id');
            var counter = 1;
            var salt    = $(this).attr('class');

            console.log('ol.rating li.'+salt);

            $('ol.rating li.'+salt).each(function(i){
            if (id >= counter) {
                $('a#'+counter).addClass("starHover");
            } else {
                $('a#'+counter).removeClass("starHover");
            }
            counter++;
            });
    });
```

Hope my question is a bit clear :)

Thanks in advance!
Nick

Comment: What does the `this` refer to in `$('ol.rating li', this)` ? And can you add your css definitions as well. It is difficult to see the intended behavior.

Comment: it refers to the ol.rating li the user touched(?) there are serval ol blocks like above on the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is working propertly (I just removed the `this` keyword from the first line): http://jsfiddle.net/yAwZz/

You are printing class to the console which is the same for all `<li>` elements. Could this be the source of confusion?

**Update:**

You are using same `id` for multiple HTML elements which is never good idea. `id` attribute must be **unique** element identificator.

You can use [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) and [.slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) jQuery methods to simplify the code and make it work as expected without using ids. Note that I used [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) event instead of [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) ad hover is called on both mouseenter and mouseleave which is in this case unnecessary:

```
$('ol.rating li').mouseenter(function(){
    var $lis = $(this).siblings("li").andSelf();
    var id   = $(this).index();

    $lis.removeClass("starHover");
    $lis.slice(0, id + 1).addClass("starHover");
});
```

You can see the code working on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yAwZz/5/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yAwZz/1/ there you see what's happening when I add a extra rating block

Comment: @Freshcoat In this fiddle, the HTML is invalid since the IDs are repeated across the document. You need to ensure unique IDs for your 'a' elements

Comment: you are right about the id's. I will change them to classes. I guess the solution of @ryadavilli will be OK to use withit for now.

Comment: That's a really nice peace of clean code you wrote there :) I am agree with what you said about the hover, mouseenter is the correct methode to use here for rating stars. Thanks, I will accept your question

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the class name of ratings different.
ex:

```
<ol class="rating1" data-rating="4">
<li class="Arad5fQEnoZlv9E59d"><a title="Super boring" class="rate starOn" id="1">1 star</a></li>
<li class="Arad5fQEnoZlv9E59d"><a title="Boring" class="rate starOn" id="2">2 stars</a></li>
<li class="Arad5fQEnoZlv9E59d"><a title="Nice" class="rate starOn" id="3">3 stars</a></li>
<li class="Arad5fQEnoZlv9E59d"><a title="Cool" class="rate starOn" id="4">4 stars</a></li>
<li class="Arad5fQEnoZlv9E59d"><a title="Super cool!" class="rate star" id="5">5 stars</a></li>
<div class="response">Score 4 By 2  ratings</div>
</ol> 
<ol class="rating2" data-rating="4">
<li class="Arad5fQEnoZlv9E59d"><a title="Super boring" class="rate starOn" id="1">1 star</a></li>
<li class="Arad5fQEnoZlv9E59d"><a title="Boring" class="rate starOn" id="2">2 stars</a></li>
<li class="Arad5fQEnoZlv9E59d"><a title="Nice" class="rate starOn" id="3">3 stars</a></li>
<li class="Arad5fQEnoZlv9E59d"><a title="Cool" class="rate starOn" id="4">4 stars</a></li>
<li class="Arad5fQEnoZlv9E59d"><a title="Super cool!" class="rate star" id="5">5 stars</a></li>
<div class="response">Score 4 By 2  ratings</div>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Updated your code to use just li and then figure out the context from within the hover. 
Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yAwZz/2/

```
$('li').hover(function(){
        console.log("hover");
        var id      = $('a', this).attr('id');
        var counter = 1;
        var salt    = $(this).attr('class');
        // get the context here.

        var parent = $(this).parent();
        console.log('ol.rating li#'+id);

        // remove the class for all elements by default.
        $('a').removeClass("starHover");

        // use the context here for adding the class
        $('li.'+salt, parent).each(function(i){
        if (id >= counter) {
            $('a#'+counter, parent).addClass("starHover");
        } else {
            $('a#'+counter, parent).removeClass("starHover");
        }
        counter++;
        });
});
```